# Issue with maxWorkerThreads and thread count

Tags: .net, asp.net, multithreading, iis-7, iis-6

I have created an ASP.NET application which creates threads in an infinite loop. I set `maxWorkerThreads` to 20 in `processModel` in `machine.config`.

When I checked the Thread count in perfmon there was around 7000 threads created in worker process.

In `PageLoad()` I have:

```
using System.Threading;
...
int count = 0;
var threadList = new System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Threading.Thread>();
try
{
  while (true)
  {
    Thread newThread = new Thread(ThreadStart(DummyCall), 1024);
    newThread.Start();
    threadList.Add(newThread);
    count++;
  }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  Response.Write(count + " : " + ex.ToString());
}
```

Function:

```
void DummyCall()
{
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000000000);
}
```

How do I restrict thread creation in ASP.NET with IIS6/7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The threads you are creating are not ASP.NET worker threads and are not restricted by the limits specified by `processModel`.

Here you are just creating plain old .NET threads and there is almost nothing but the maximum amount memory available to the process to cap the number of threads you can create.

I'd consider using the [managed `ThreadPool`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ka9477y.aspx) class instead.

However you should be questioning why you need to be spawning background worker threads in your ASP.NET pages. This is generally considered to be a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

How are you creating the threads? If you are using `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` then I would expect no more than 20 threads to be running at any given time.

If, however, you are spawning threads and simply calling `.Start()` then you can create as many as you like.

Comment: then is there any way we can restrict this??